# What's the proper way to initialize a class_attribute in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

What's the proper way to initialize a `class_attribute` in Rails?

I am using this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  class_attribute :foobar
  self.foobar = []

  # ...

end
```

Which seems to work fine, but also seems to look a bit non-Railsy to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Everything is described here: http://apidock.com/rails/Class/class_attribute

If you click on "Show source" you will see there are no options available to set default value. You are doing it right.

Comment: FYI I didn't downvote you but I could not see any endorsement for what I'm doing on the URL you pasted. I had actually already looked to see if there was an option for a default value. There is enough magic in Rails that I wanted to get a definitive answer. After searching around I found this official Rails guide that is using the same method of initialization as I am http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html#class-attributes so I guess it's all good!

Comment: Will upvote, sorry about that. Glad you found it. Pls edit the question so I can correct this.

Comment: You have to change at least one character in your question, I cannot upvote otherwise...

Answer (score 5):

A `default` option was added on branch master of Rails this year, check: https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/29270. With this change, you can do:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  class_attribute :foobar, default: []
end
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering: that's for rails version >= 5.2.0

Answer (score 1):

What you've done works well (unless you are inheriting).

If you are inheriting from this class you can use the `inherited` method to avoid 'leaking'.

```
def self.inherited(sub_class)
  self.foobar = self.foobar.clone
  # or `self.foobar = []`
end
```

Comment: DEPRECATION WARNING: It looks like something (probably a gem/plugin) is overriding the ActiveRecord::Base.inherited method. It is important that this hook executes so that your models are set up correctly. A workaround has been added to stop this causing an error in 3.2, but future versions will simply not work if the hook is overridden. If you are using Kaminari, please upgrade as it is known to have had this problem.